# Linear Interpolation in TwinCAT

Tags: twincat, codesys, st

I'm trying to use `FB_CTRL_LIN_INTERPOLATION,` which exists in `Controller Toolbox` in TwinCAT3 as described in this [link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf4100_tc3_controller_toolbox/245469323.html&id=).

Unfortunately, the examples on the Infosys site are not practical; for example, there is no data type `FLOAT` on twincat3 at all; it can replace with `REAL` or `LREAL` in the next revision of the site!

By the way, here is my first attempt to implement the example.

The deceleration part is:

```
VAR
    linInt:FB_CTRL_LIN_INTERPOLATION;
    stParams       : ST_CTRL_LIN_INTERPOLATION_PARAMS;
    fIn           : LREAL;
    fManValue     : LREAL;
    bExtrapolate  : BOOL;
    eMode         : E_CTRL_MODE;
    
    fOut                        : LREAL;
    bInIsGreaterThanMaxElement  : BOOL;
    bInIsLessThanMinElement     : BOOL;
    eState                      : E_CTRL_STATE;
    eErrorId                    : E_CTRL_ERRORCODES;
    bError                      : BOOL;
    
    Data: ARRAY[1..6, 1..2] OF INT := [10, 15, 21, 22, 30, 40, 7, 10, 9, 2, 3, 6];
END_VAR
```

and the body part is :

```
stParams.pDataTable_ADR:=ADR(Data);
stParams.tCtrlCycleTime:=T#4S;
stParams.tTaskCycleTime:=T#2S;
stParams.nDataTable_SIZEOF:=SIZEOF(Data);
stParams.nDataTable_NumberOfRows:=6;


linInt(fIn:=fIn,
    fManValue:=fManValue,
    bExtrapolate:=bExtrapolate,
    eMode:=emode,
    fOut=>fOut,
    bInIsGreaterThanMaxElement=>bInIsGreaterThanMaxElement,
    bInIsGreaterThanMaxElement=>bInIsLessThanMinElement,
    eState=>eState,
    eErrorId=>eErrorId,
    bError=>bError,
    stParams:=stParams);
```

I do not have any idea what is the meaning of `Size of the n x 2 array` for the  Description of `nDataTable_SIZEOF` so I used `SIZEOF(Data)` command to assign a value to it.
exactly I now wonder what the 24 is!

[image]

as shown in the following figure, there is an error with the `table description.`

any help would be appreciated if someone clears it to me what is the meaning of `stparams` with detail here and how I can handle this example completely.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your data table needs to be "ARRAY[x..y, 1..2] OF FLOAT", not INT.

The FLOAT datatype is defined as an alias inside the library as a LREAL or REAL. See: [InfoSys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf4100_tc3_controller_toolbox/245508619.html?id=9060504954589953283)

Comment: Finally, I fixed it with `LREAL,` but according to IEC61131-3, `FLOAT` in the system manager is equal to `REAL`; alternatively, the data type `DOUBLE` in the system manager is equivalent to `LREAL` data type in IEC61131-3.
For more information, see this [link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_system/html/tcsysmgr_datatypecomparison.htm&id=)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with TwinCAT, however implementing a linear interpolator shouldn't be too difficult.

[Here's an example Function Block.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aRCa0XWF4M_5mSqWuZWfZrZnId0ufwAt/view?usp=sharing)

Assuming you have a `data` array, you can interpolate using the following formulae:

```pascal
// find the interval of points x falls into. let `i` be the left point of that interval.
y := (x - data[i, 1]) / (data[i + 1, 1] - data[i, 1]) * (data[i + 1, 2] - data[i, 2]) + data[i, 2];
```